encoding a movie with discontinuities in video and audio
I'm encoding a movie (Avatar-The Way of the Water) from the DVD. The DVD timestamps have discontinuities in both video and audio:
[vist#0:1/mpeg2video @ 0x594d65657440] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=480): -24160289, new offset= 4452355191
[aist#0:2/ac3 @ 0x594d65648680] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=128): 24192289, new offset= 4428162902
frame=110449 fps=5.0 q=32.1 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.52 bitrate=1301.8kbitframe=110450 fps=5.0 q=25.9 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.56 bitrate=1301.8kbit[aist#0:2/ac3 @ 0x594d65648680] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=128): -24128289, new offset= 4452291191
frame=110451 fps=5.0 q=28.4 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.60 bitrate=1301.8kbitframe=110455 fps=5.0 q=32.1 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.76 bitrate=1301.7kbitframe=110456 fps=5.0 q=26.2 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.80 bitrate=1301.7kbitframe=110457 fps=5.0 q=28.4 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:09.84 bitrate=1301.7kbitframe=110461 fps=5.0 q=32.4 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.00 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110462 fps=5.0 q=26.1 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.04 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110463 fps=5.0 q=28.3 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.08 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110467 fps=5.0 q=32.1 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.24 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110468 fps=5.0 q=26.2 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.28 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110469 fps=5.0 q=26.4 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.32 bitrate=1301.6kbitframe=110474 fps=5.0 q=32.0 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.52 bitrate=1301.5kbitframe=110474 fps=5.0 q=32.0 size=  707072KiB time=01:14:10.52 bitrate=1301.5kbit[libopus @ 0x594d65625f40] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aost#0:1/libopus @ 0x594d656eb880] Non-monotonic DTS; previous: 4452121, current: 4452109; changing to 4452121. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aost#0:1/libopus @ 0x594d656eb880] Non-monotonic DTS; previous: 4452129, current: 4452117; changing to 4452129. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

So when encoding, ffmpeg does its best. The resulting file though, it plays fine with ffplay, however with mpv on reaching a discontinuity, the video freezes, the audio continues, then the video sprints to catch up.
I think I've tried most methods of doing things with the timesteps, but what I think is happening is a different correction is applied to audio and video.
So any ideas what to change, or should I just use ffplay?

Which method did you use for the concatenation of the VOBs: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#samecodec ? Have you tried both?

I'm seeing similar warnings being emitted when I try to extract the video and audio streams from a DVD with ffmpeg 7.0.2, and I don't think I used to see them when working on the same DVD with an older version of ffmpeg. Probably there has been some new regression in the MPEG-PS demuxer or the concatentation code. (I always use the concat "protocol" (concat:) for DVD VOBs btw.)
When you try to remux/re-encode directly from there, ffmpeg would use the timestamp from the input container, I think, which is probably the cause of the frozen-playback issue, as it ends up causing corrupted timestamps to be used by the muxer / written to the output container.
However, I can't reproduce the issue, as in, for one I don't know what you muxer / container format you use for the output file, and for two, I don't know whether you are just remuxing or actually re-encoding the video, and I can't exactly remux directly from the VOBs anyway, because often I seem to need -fflags genpts but ffmpeg would somehow end up stuck. (I think that was sort of a long time issue.)
Nevertheless, even with the warning shown, I don't find it having problem just extracting the stream(s):
ffmpeg -i 'concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB|VTS_01_5.VOB|VTS_01_6.VOB' -map 0:v -c:v copy -f mpeg2video - | md5sum

According to the MD5, it still gives me the exact same video stream, and I can mux the raw MPEG-2 video stream into e.g. an mkv without any problem with -fflags genpts.
(You do need to specify -framerate manually in addition; the value would either be 30000/1001 for NTSC DVDs or 25 for PAL DVDs, or 24000/1001 if there was a "perfect" soft pull down that could be and had been removed by you. But IIRC even if you don't do it the resulted wrong metadata won't really cause problem to playback in most cases).
In my experience of working on the few DVDs that is modern enough (like post-2000), the timestamps in container isn't really important because in reality they are not really used to "sync" video and audio. The creator would really just mess with the video and/or audio streams, if that's even necessary, so that they are in sync anyway even when "self-contained".
Yet while you can extract also the audio streams (ffmpeg support outputting raw AC3/DTS files), and then remux/re-encode them into whatever you want (with multple -i and -map), it's probably easier to just use e.g. mkvtoolnix to get a remux first (and start from there if you need to re-encode). Unfortunately it has no support for getting DVD subtitles into the output (even ffmpeg has only partial support, as in, the palette would be lost because it does not resides in the VOBs). If you need DVD subtitles you'd need to resort to makemkv (which is a non-free software).

Yes, I to am on version 7.0.2.
The command used for encoding was:
[code block]ffmpeg -i /tmp/Avatar-TheWayOfTheWater.mpg -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -preset slower -af "pan=stereo|FL < 1.0FL + 0.707FC + 0.707BL|FR < 1.0FR + 0.707FC + 0.707BR" -c:a libopus -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 Avatar-TheWayOfTheWater.mkv
The original DVD had the discontinuities in it, but yes would get same effect with concat.
I've tried -fflags genpts in the past but it didn't help with this movie.
And yes when the glitches happen, ffmpeg typically drops a frame or two

@DavidSummers My point was really that to deal with this apparent regression, you may want/need to strip the MPEG-PS containment and mux from the raw streams (or remux with/into something else other than ffmpeg/MPEG-PS)  first, in other words to avoid having ffmpeg producing the final output from MPEG-PS input, so that it won't be affected by the broken demuxer. To be frank, I don't even know much about -fflags genpts. All I know is that I at least need it when I remux from some DVD VOBs / raw MPEG-2 video streams, especially when the output is mkv.

@DavidSummers (I could be wrong but I am under the impression that ffmpeg cares much about what information the demuxer provides, as in, the muxer would be sort of fed with the information even when it can be re-generated "from scratch" in most cases. Therefore there could be a significant impact in having the streams extracted or remuxed by something else first. And I don't know of a "direct" way to make ffmpeg "ignore" the demuxer as much as it can. The manual states using -r $frame_rate as an input option would make it ignore the PTS, but it does not seem to actually work as expected.)

tried -r25 on both input and output with -fflags genpts this encoded the film with no dropped frames. The detected speed on the original movie was PAL 25.000. After first glitch, sound and video get out of sink. Whats happening if you look at the  DTS stamps on each fame, is that for the first 90 minutes or so, the DTS time regularly resets to zero. Yes can strip out the video - may try HandBrake, but its not my favourite program!
